# Не получается вывести данные в в форму

Tags: html, css, python, django, forms

Создал форму при помощи Django Forms но не могу ее вывести с помощью form.as_p

vies.py

```
def get_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Comment(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    else:
        form = Comment()

    return render(request, 'news/post.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class Comment(forms.Form):
    WhoAreYou = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    textComment = forms.Textarea()
```

post.html

```
{% block content %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1 class=" text-info">{{articles.title}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <p> {{articles.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
            <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликованно: {{articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
      </div>

        <h4>Comments</h4>


    <form action="." method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Уверены, что эта функция отрабатывает?

Comment: Точно не уверен

Comment: А всё остальное (кроме формы) нормально выводится?

Comment: Выведите сырой контекст на страницу и посмотрите, что приходит. Еще в шаблоне есть переменная `articles`, хотя в контекст ее не передаете. Если статьи отображаются, то нужно проверить, точно тот контекст к шаблону приходит? Может что-то с контроллерами напутали?

Comment: @NeITdirect так проверьте. Такое рщущение что вы где-то с шаблонами натупили.